# Auditing for Security and Events in multiple architecture system

Tags: c#, business-objects, auditing

We have an application that uses various technologies and frameworks. It is 3 tier, uses Datasets, Object Mapping, MVC, inline SQL with Parameters, Various .NET There is lots going on  some third party and lots custom stuff of five years of development with many different developers thru the years. We use Log4Net for logging but want to move some stuff to an auditing system and begin robust auditing in that system. Stuff we are looking to audit is:

- Authentication events like attempted login, sucessfull
- Password changes and failures
- Links clicked
- Location of user
- IP Address
- Certain DML events
- Etc.

Is there any good way to accomplish this that is somewhat efficient? I was thinking of having a Domain Business Object that we can send the events to via certain functions. We could pass the data as the object like userchanges -> toXML(). Right now we are just looking at the new values and not old+new. There were ideas of adding method attributes and use reflection but I think that will slow things down too much. I think SQL auditing is not in my scope, they do their own thing and my scope is to do app auditing.

We are open to third party solutions and open to other ideas.

Thanks